# How can I set the text from the input field to empty?

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to reset the text from 3 input fields to empty after a click on a button. When i click on the button "Speichern" the text stays in the input field but I want that these input fields are empty after the click.

```
<div class="cInputChangePWColor">
   <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
      <input class="cInputWidth" placeholder="Altes Passwort" ng-model="passwordOld">
   </div>
   <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
       <input class="cInputWidth" placeholder="Neues Passwort" ng-model="passwordNew">
   </div>
   <div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace">
       <input class="cInputWidth" placeholder="Passwort bestätigen" ng-model="passwordNewConfirmed">
   </div>
   <div class="cClearFloat cButtonPosition">
       <button class="cButtonSpeichernSettings" ng-click="showAlertchangePassword(); setTextDefault()">Speichern</button>
       <button class="cButtonAbbrechenSettings" ng-click="isShownchangePw = false; isShownSettings = false">Abbrechen</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried it like this but it's not working.

```
$scope.setTextDefault = function() {
    $scope.passwordOld == '';
    $scope.passwordNew == '';
    $scope.passwordNewConfirmed == '';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change  `$scope.passwordOld == '';` to  `$scope.passwordOld = '';`

Comment: it's working. Sometimes im just stupid :). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.reset = function(form) {

    var fields = Object.keys(form).filter(function(key) {
        return (key.indexOf('$') !== 0);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var name = fields[i];
        var field = form[name];
        field.$setViewValue(undefined);
        field.$render();
    }

    form.$setPristine();
    form.$setUntouched();


};
```

You can also use the reset function. You just need to wrap the DOM in a `Form` and pass the `$scope.formName` to reset function.